# How can I apply TF2 Conditions to bots in MvM?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-mann-vs-machine

I'm creating a custom population (`.pop`) file for Mann vs Machine, and want to be able to apply condition codes (like the `TF2_AddCondition` function, or the `addcond` cheat command) to a specific bot when it arrives.

Some examples of what I'm trying to accomplish:

- Upon arrival, a bot has 100% Critical Hit chance for 30 seconds. (`TFCond_CritOnDamage`)
- Or: Upon spawning, coat this bot in Mad Milk (`TFCond_Milked`) for infinite duration. (That would mean that all attacks against this bot return health to the attacker.)

The `.pop` files have support for event triggers eg `StartWaveOutput`, but the documentation is virtually nonexistent.

Does anyone know how I can apply TF2 Conditions to bots in MvM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this with population files alone on a vanilla (unmodded) TF2 server.

If you are open to hosting a dedicated server on a Linux machine, you can achieve this using [sigsegv's SourceMod extensions](https://github.com/sigsegv-mvm/sigsegv-mvm). You will, of course, first need to [install SourceMod](https://wiki.alliedmods.net/Installing_SourceMod). Then, you can use [sigsegv's 
addcond syntax](https://github.com/sigsegv-mvm/sigsegv-mvm/wiki/PopFile-Mods%3A-TFBot#addcond) to do exactly what you want:

```
TFBot
{
    // ...
    AddCond [$SIGSEGV]
    {
        Index 27 // Mad Milk
        // No Duration = lasts forever
    }

    AddCond [$SIGSEGV]
    {
        Index 56 // Misc. Crit Boost
        Duration 30.0
    }
}
```

While parts of sigsegv's extensions work on Windows, I don't believe the TFBot extensions do, so you're out of luck in case you can't use Linux.

Comment: Thanks! I already do run a dedicated server and have SourceMod and my own extension, so that's no problem. (And it is on Linux. Linux all the way.) I'll check out sigsegv's source; it seems to have a ton of stuff in it.

Comment: Derp, I now see that you have an Ask Ubuntu account, lol. Good luck setting it up!

Comment: Haven't yet actually proven this in practice, but it ought to work, so I'm accepting the answer. Thanks!